# Fragment navigation with back button undesired behavior

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation

I have an issue with onBackPressed() implementation in my app. I have a single fragment with differents tags. The user could navigate between fragments with a Navigation View and the back button. Everything works as expected except when FragmentTransaction goes like this:

Initial Fragment->A->B->C->A

When I use back button to return, the behavior I want to achieve is A->C->B->Initial.

Instead, I get A->B->C->A->Initial

How can I acomplish my desired behavior?

This is what I have so far:

```
private int backStackEntries = 0;

    public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d(TAG,"Number of fragments in back: "+backStackEntries);

    NewsListFragment fragment = (NewsListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentFrag);

    backStackEntries-=1;
    if(backStackEntries<0)
        backStackEntries = 0;

    if(fragment.getTag().equals(News_TAG[0])){
        if(fragment.getParserMaker().isRunning()){
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
        else{
            finish();
        }
    }
    else{
        currentFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(backStackEntries).getName();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .hide(fragment)
                .show(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentFrag))
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .commit();
    }
}

private void makeFragmentTransaction(String[] urls, int item,String _TAG) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArray("urls", urls);

    NewsListFragment newsFragment = (NewsListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(_TAG);
    if(newsFragment == null){
        newsFragment = new NewsListFragment();
    }
    newsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    if(currentFrag == null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, newsFragment, _TAG)
                .addToBackStack(_TAG)
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .commit();
        currentFrag = _TAG;
    }

    else if(!newsFragment.isAdded()){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .hide(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentFrag))
                .add(R.id.container,newsFragment,_TAG)
                .addToBackStack(_TAG)
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .commit();
        currentFrag = _TAG;
        backStackEntries+=1;
    }
    else if(!currentFrag.equals(_TAG)){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .hide(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentFrag))
                .show(newsFragment)
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .commit();
        backStackEntries+=1;
        currentFrag = _TAG;

    }

    navigationView.setCheckedItem(item);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}
```

Adding the last **backStackEntries+=1;** makes the weird behavior and erasing that line makes the deal BUT it creates another Transaction issue:

Initial(going back)->B->C

Pressing back button: C->Initial

I have also tried making transactions like this:

```
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, newsFragment, _TAG)
            .addToBackStack(_TAG)
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .commit();
    currentFrag = _TAG;
```

And onBackPressed like this:

```
NewsListFragment fragment = (NewsListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentFrag);
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        if (fragment.getParserMaker().isRunning()) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

This also cause the undesired behavior and popBackStack() removes fragment, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the same problem, I solved it by implementing my own history stack for the fragments. everytime that I wanted to add a fragment to the stack, I would look through the stack and removed the fragment with the same class as the one I was gonna add (if there was one)